# Android: How to cast in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, casting

I would like to know how to cast in kotlin.

Here is java code that I would like to perform in Kotlin.

**Java**

```
 public void moveToSettingActivity(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ((Activity)context).finishAffinity();
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
 fun moveToSettingActivity(context: Context){
    val intent = Intent(context,SettingsActivity::class.java)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

I would like to know how to perform `((Activity)context)` in kotlin.

Comment: Thanks. `(context as Activity).finishAffinity()` works as expected

Comment: [The docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator)

Answer (score 0):

While `(context as Activity)` does work, it's best to add some safety around it:

```
val activity = checkNotNull(context as? Activity) { "context is not an Activity" }
```

Because `Context` could be several things, like an `Application` instance.